# Jupyter lab is showing 'jupyter-lab' not found in Anaconda prompt

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter-lab

I am using anaconda and from the base environment of it, I can easily open jupyter notebook and jupyter lab. I have another environment named  **gpu_jupyter** which was also running fine. But after installing nltk on base enviroment (using conda install), jupyter lab is not working on gpu_jupyter env. It is showing

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\emt\anaconda3\envs\gpu_jupyter\Scripts\jupyter-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\emt\anaconda3\envs\gpu_jupyter\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\command.py", line 285, in main
    command = _jupyter_abspath(subcommand)
  File "C:\Users\emt\anaconda3\envs\gpu_jupyter\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\command.py", line 124, in _jupyter_abspath
    raise Exception(
Exception: Jupyter command `jupyter-lab` not found.
```

I tried with installing the **nb_conda**. The ipykernel is also installed and **jupyter notebook** is also working fine. Jupyter lab is also can be run using the base env

I also tried to add path but somehow my Continumm folder is missing. [This](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/8x13tq/anaconda_continuum_folder_missing/) link discuss that problem but the solution for that folder is not given.

Is there anything that I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

installing using `pip` solved my issue. My env is created via miniconda.

```
pip install jupyterlab
```

Then run it via miniconda command prompt by

```
jupyter lab
```

Comment: Yes it mostly solves the issue. Just to make sure, I also had to install `nb_conda`.